# Разбивка текста на составляющие. Регулярные выражения. Паттерн Composite

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте!
У меня задание: разбить текст из книги по программированию (т.е. кроме обычно текста там содержатся еще и листинги), используя "регулярки", на слова, пункт. знаки, предложения, абзац и так далее. И еще нужно из этих частей его собрать в исходном виде. Ну и потом произвести дополнительные изменения по заданию. Обязательное условие - реализация паттерна Composite. Вот тут и загвоздка. 
Как бы регулярные выражения ясны и сам паттерн тоже несложный. Но как его тут применить. Конечно, понятно, что элементы текста могут быть как узлами (предложение, абзац), так и листьями (слово (если его не разбивать на символы), пункт. знак). Но как это спроектировать? Наверное, будет один интерфейс, в котором будут необходимые функции добавления, удаления, получения (которые для листьев будут UnsupportedOperation), ну и какая-то функция для прохода по дереву (или что-то в этом роде). Просто не могу догнать как мне паттерн все упростит. Сказали, что классов в модели должно значительно уменшиться.

Без этого паттерна. Я бы тупо в классе предложения держал ArrayList с пунктуацией и словами. В классе Абзац ArrayList с предложениями и т.д.

Может кто-нибудь понял тот бред, что я написал? Либо кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным применением паттерна Composite? =(
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все `entities` в вашей программе очень похожи поэтому нет смысла выносить их в отдельные классы. вам достаточно будет 1го базового класса для того чтоб хранить каждую из них.

Предположим что у вас есть класс который хранит данные (реализующий паттерн композит). У которого есть поле тип значения которого берутся из `enum`. `enum` описывает все возможные составляющие: текст, абзац, предложение, слово, итд итп.

Вся необходимая логика у вас будет вкручена в одном методе, который в зависимости от типа будет разбивать значение на более мелкие части.

Например:

1. метод `parse` на вход получает объект с типом текст. После применения соответствующего паттерна вы получаете список элементов которые соответсвуют уже абзацам (вы добавляете их к элементу текст и вызываете рекурсивно метод `parse` уже для них).
2. в результате абзацы разбиваются на предложения

p.s. следующий уровень вложенности рекурсии разобьет предложения на слова + знаки пунктуации, итд итп.

p.s.s. лучше всего задать `regexp` для каждого отдельного типа как параметр конструктора `enum` константы

класс композита у вас будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
class Entity {
  private EntityType type;
  private List<EntityType> parts = new LinkedList<EntityType>();
  private String text;

  public Entity(EntityType type, String text) {} // call setType, setText

  public List<EntityType> getParts() {} // implement
  public void addPart(Entity e) {} // implement

  // implement getters and setters here
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что не поленились ответить! Все понял. Правда, пока не особо представляю как рекурсию реализую, но логически все предельно ясно. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: > Правда, пока не особо представляю как рекурсию реализую, но логически все предельно ясно. Еще раз спасибо!

очень просто вы вызываете метод parse, и передаете ему элемент который нужно разобрать на части (в начале для элемента текст). метод парс с помощью регулярки разобивает текст на абзацы. вы создаете элементы и добавляете их к элементу текст. потом внутри этого метода вызываете его же для того чтоб спарсить элементы которые вы только что добавили

Comment: Да, я уже вчера разобрался. Спасибо Вам огромное =))). Очень даже неплохо вышло.